# How do I write a yocto/bitbake recipe to replace the default vsftpd.conf file with my own file?

Tags: linux, yocto, recipe, vsftpd

I want to replace the default vsftpd.conf file with my own file!
My bitbake file looks following:

**bbexample_1.0.bb**

```
DESCRIPTION = "Configuration and extra files for TX28"
LICENSE = "CLOSED"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = ""

S = "${WORKDIR}"

SRC_URI += " \
    file://ld.so.conf \
    file://nginx/nginx.conf \
    file://init.d/myscript.sh"

inherit allarch

do_install () {
    install -d ${D}${sysconfdir}
    install -d ${D}${sysconfdir}/nginx
    install -d ${D}${sysconfdir}/init.d
    rm -f ${D}${sysconfdir}/ld.so.conf
    install -m 0755 ${WORKDIR}/ld.so.conf ${D}${sysconfdir}
    install -m 0755 ${WORKDIR}/nginx/nginx.conf ${D}${sysconfdir}/nginx/
    install -m 0755 ${WORKDIR}/init.d/myscript.sh ${D}${sysconfdir}/init.d/
}
```

**bbexample_1.0.bbappend**

```
FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/${PN}-${PV}:"

SRC_URI += " \
    file://vsftpd.conf"

do_install_append () {
    install -m 0755 ${WORKDIR}/vsftpd.conf ${D}${sysconfdir}
}
```

But, the file could not be replaced!
What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should add to your recipe:

```
FILES_${PN} += " file you installed"
```

Answer (score 4):

What you need to do is to use a bbappend in your own layer,

`vsftpd` recipe is located in `meta-openembedded/meta-networking/recipes-daemons`

Thus you need to create a file called `vstfpd_%.bbappend` (`%` makes it valid for every version)

This file must be located in `<your-layer>/meta-networking/recipes-daemons`. You also need to put your custom `vsftpd.conf` in `<your-layer>/meta-networking/recipes-daemons/vsftpd` folder

Its content should be:

```
FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/files:"

do_install_append(){
    install -m 644 ${WORKDIR}/vsftpd.conf ${D}${sysconfdir}
}
```

Example from meta-openembedded [here](https://github.com/openembedded/meta-openembedded/blob/master/meta-systemd/oe-core/recipes-connectivity/dhcp/dhcp_%25.bbappend)

Comment: To be sure you're bbappend is loaded. Use `bitbake-layers show-appends | grep vsftpd`

Comment: This was very helpful: worked for me.  One comment though: you say that the bbappend must be located in "<your-layer>/meta-networking/recipes-daemons/vsftpd". I do not think it needs to be in a path which matches the path of the recipe being appended to.  Only the file name must match.  I have a different path, and it picked up the bbappend.

Comment: You are right, it is not mandatory, but it is very convenient to find it easily